# Javascript function is working on main page but stops on second pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to make a website with ReactJS. In my website I have a slice button on the main page;

When you click the slice button, each side shows a different image.

I add links to the Menu bar as well for the slice button (I am going to call Left - Right) so when you click the link, the first go to the part of the main page then it moves the slice button and shows the image.

I do not have any problem with the links when I am on the main page but the problem is; I am using same Menu bar for all pages and when I click the `Left` and the `Right` right links in the Menu on a different page it stops.

The links open the main page but stay the beginning of the main page.

**UPDATE 2:** Although the problem is not with the `Toggle button` but I want to add the toggle function in the main page that you can see all.

Note: I remove `toggle button` but links are not working (Right I cannot see the buttons when I remove the function but when I click the link in the menu, the page does not link to exact part of the button placed in the main page so still I have the same problem .)

Here is my `ChangeViewButtonClick` function in main;

```
import React, { Component } from "react";


class Main extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      view: "Left"
    };
    this.ChangeViewButtonClick = this.ChangeViewButtonClick.bind(this);
    this.ChangeViewToggle = this.ChangeViewToggle.bind(this);
  }

   togglePopup() {
    this.setState({
      showPopup: !this.state.showPopup
    });
  }

  ChangeViewToggle() {
    if (this.refs.toggle.state.checked === true) {
      this.setState({ view: "Left" });
      this.refs.toggle.state.checked = false
    } else  {
      this.setState({ view: "Right" });
      this.refs.toggle.state.checked = true
    }
  }
  ChangeViewButtonClick(view) {
    if (view === "Left") {
      this.setState({ view: "Left" });
      this.refs.toggle.state.checked = true
    } else if (view === "Right") {
      this.setState({ view: "Right" });
      this.refs.toggle.state.checked = false
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h1> 
           <footer className="togglefooter">
            <label>
                  &nbsp;
                  <span style={{ color: "black", fontWeight: "normal" }}>
                   Left
                    &nbsp;
                  </span>
                  <Toggle
                    id="toggle"
                    ref="toggle"
                    defaultChecked={this.state.view}
                    icons={false}
                    onChange={() => this.ChangeViewToggle()}
                  />
                  <span style={{ color: "black", fontWeight: "normal" }}>
                    &nbsp;
                    Right
                  </span>
                </label>
              </footer>
        </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and this is my Menu Page ;

```
import React from 'react';
import { Collapse, Navbar, NavbarToggler, NavbarBrand, NavLink} from 'reactstrap';
import { HashLink as Link } from 'react-router-hash-link';


class Menu extends React.Component {  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    };
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Navbar light expand="md">
        <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
        <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
          <nav className="nav">
            <ul className="nav__menu">
              <li className="nav__menu-item">
                <NavLink to="#" tag= {Link} >
                  Images
                </NavLink>
                <Image_SubMenu ChangeViewButtonClick{this.props.ChangeViewButtonClick}/>
              </li>
              <li className="nav__menu-item">
                <NavLink tag={Link} to="/main#something">
                  Something
                </NavLink>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    );
  }
}

class Image_SubMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul className="nav__submenu">
        <li className="nav__submenu-item ">
          <NavLink to="/main#map" tag={Link} onClick={evt => this.props.ChangeViewButtonClick("Left")}>
            Left Image
          </NavLink> 
        </li>
        <li className="nav__submenu-item ">
          <NavLink to="/main#map" tag={Link} onClick={evt => this.props.ChangeViewButtonClick("Right")} >
            Right Image
          </NavLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

export default Menu;
```

How can I fix the link that if I click on the link anywhere on the website then shows me `Left` or `Right` images

I found a few articles about `delegated events` unfortunately I could not figure out.

Thanks in advance

Note that this is only part of the code and just paste the part that you need so if I miss something please tell me so can be a few typos.

**Update:** I would like to add my other two pages here because the information that I shared might not be enough.

I am trying to click links that are inside the `Menu` and I have the problem

About page:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactGA from 'react-ga'
//Import components
import Footer from "./components/Footer.js";
import Menu from "./components/Menu.js";

function About(props) {  
  return ( 
    <div>
      <div className="bgded overlay">
        {/* Menu Component */}
        <Menu ChangeViewButtonClick={props.ChangeViewButtonClick}/>
      </div>
      {/* Start of Project Aims */}
      <a id ="aims" />
      <div className="wrapper row3">
        <main className="hoc container clear" style={{ paddingTop: "30px" }}>
          <article className="one_third first" style={{ width: "100%" }}>
            <h4 className="font-x2 font-x3">
              Something about project
            </h4>
            <p>Something is here too..</p>
          </article>
          <div className="clear" />
        </main>
      </div>
      {/* Footer Component */}
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default About;
```

Report Page:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
import ReactDependentScript from 'react-dependent-script';
import Footer from "./components/Footer.js";
import Menu from "./components/Menu.js"
//Import PNG Image
//import { domain } from "./config.json";
import GraphHover from "./components/GraphHover.js";

class report extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      displayGraph: "none",
      graphTitle: null,
      graphPreview: null,
      graphHoverLeft: "0",
      previewImages: null,
    };
    this._onMouseLeave = this._onMouseLeave.bind(this);
    this.DisplayHoverGraph = this.DisplayHoverGraph.bind(this);
  }

  _onMouseLeave(evt) {
    this.setState({ displayGraph: "none" });
  }

  DisplayHoverGraph(input, image, evt) {
    //Disable hover effect if on a mobile device
    if (!this.props.isMobileDevice) {
      this.setState({
        graphTitle: input,
        previewImage: image,
        displayGraph: "inline"
      });

      if (evt.clientX < window.screen.width / 2) {
        this.setState({ graphHoverLeft: "1200px" });
      } else {
        this.setState({ graphHoverLeft: "0" });
      }
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(window.test)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <GraphHover
          position="fixed"
          top={this.state.graphHoverTop}
          left={this.state.graphHoverLeft}
          displayPreview={true}
          display={this.state.displayGraph}
          graphTitle={this.state.graphTitle}
          previewImage={this.state.previewImage}
          graphHeadingSize={this.state.graphHeadingSize}
          width={this.state.graphHoverWidth}
          height={this.state.graphHoverHeight}
        />
        <div className="bgded overlay">
          {/* Menu */}
          <Menu ChangeViewButtonClick={this.props.ChangeViewButtonClick} />
        </div>
        <div className="wrapper row3">
          <a id="sumary" />
          <main className="hoc container clear" style={{ paddingTop: "30px" }}>
            <div className="clear" />
          </main>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default report;
```

Comment: YOu don't pass `ChangeViewButtonClick` function into Menu component

Comment: @axis if you could add your routing config it would be a little helpful. Because, I can make sure that I can mimic the same

Comment: @axis can u check this link and tell me if this is what u were trying to do. https://codesandbox.io/s/yp4yjp82v1

Comment: if you have the repo, please share it here. I have suspicion because it is the Collapse is doing something.

Comment: Hi @vdj4y. I removed collapse function after your point. Although collapse is not active if screen size is not mobile screen size but  I am sorry same.

Comment: The best way is to check is to clone your code. But my assumption is this. There is an element that cover the button. So when you click you are clicking that element. Try open the chrome debugger and resize your browser and point the pointer to that element. see if anything invisible is blocking your button. I thought it is Collapse. but it could be something else

Comment: Can you show the menu component

Comment: https://reactstrap.github.io/components/navbar/ you can find here

Comment: @Axis could you help us by creating a codesandbox.io snippet with your code?

Comment: Can you share how you pass the prop ChangeViewButtonClick to your About page and Report page ?

Comment: @Saraband, sorry I could not get your question. How can I pass the prop?

Comment: @Axis could you show an image of show it should look like and how it looks at the moment on the other pages?

Comment: @Axis share the code where you are using About & Report pages.

Comment: Sorry @demonofthemist might I did not understand your question. These two pages are external pages that when you click then a new pages are open. What would you like to I share?

Comment: can't you make a codesandbox?

Comment: In your report component do a console.log(this.props) in the render function. Check the output.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the prop ChangeViewButtonClick via the parent Class (In your case, Main ) to the child class (In your case the class About or class Report ).

So your structure would be like this -
 Main
 ----About
 ----Report.

The reason I am mentioning that about and report will be child of your Main class because they are accessing the prop function  like this `<Menu ChangeViewButtonClick={this.props.ChangeViewButtonClick} />` where this.props.ChangeViewButtonClick should be made available to report and about page.

Note: You might need to add a navigation logic to load the respective pages. I will give  a simple snippet below

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Menu from './Menu'
import report from "./report"
import about from "./about"

class Main extends React.Component{

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      view: "Left"
   };
 this.ChangeViewButtonClick = this.ChangeViewButtonClick.bind(this);
 }

    ChangeViewButtonClick(view) {
    if (view === "Left") {
      this.setState({ view: "Left" });
      this.refs.toggle.state.checked = true
    } else if (view === "Right") {
      this.setState({ view: "Right" });
      this.refs.toggle.state.checked = false
    }
  }

render(){
return(
    <div>
        <h1>Main Page is Here </h1>
        // Some navigation logic between the pages below
        <report onChangeViewButtonClick={this.ChangeViewButtonClick} />
        <about onChangeViewButtonClick={this.ChangeViewButtonClick} />

    </div>
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi do you know your suggestion brings all external pages in the main page? Which is actually not useful also this is not working unfortunately

Comment: @Axis, What I have added is just a snippet. Also, if your external pages have a component that is attached in all pages and you want to change the attached component from your external page component, then there has to be a common point of intersection. In this case, I mentioned the Main component

Answer (score 0):

You have `ChangeViewButtonClick` function in `Main` component, but you don't pass this function into `Menu` component

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Menu from './Menu'

class Main extends React.Component{

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      view: "Left"
   };
 this.ChangeViewButtonClick = this.ChangeViewButtonClick.bind(this);
 }

    ChangeViewButtonClick(view) {
    if (view === "Left") {
      this.setState({ view: "Left" });
      this.refs.toggle.state.checked = true
    } else if (view === "Right") {
      this.setState({ view: "Right" });
      this.refs.toggle.state.checked = false
    }
  }

render(){
return(
    <div>
        <h1>Main Page is Here </h1>
        <Menu onChangeViewButtonClick={this.ChangeViewButtonClick} />
    </div>
  );
 }
}
```

And in Menu component you can receive `onChangeViewButtonClick` property and call it in action like `this.props.onChangeViewButtonClick('view')`

Comment: Hi @Marty thank you your progress for my question. The first I updated my question. The second is I am passing the `Menu` component in other pages because I do not have any problem in Main page Although I tried before but result is same unfortunately.